# Change the context for your Application

Tags: grails

I have a Grails Application:  MyApplication

This means the URLS all have `MyApplication` in them, when I do `grails run-app`.  I would like to change this to `myapplication`  or better still `myapp`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need an entry in `Config.groovy` regarding app context root as:

```
grails.app.context = '/myapp'
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice little gem of a setting. I didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the value of `app.name` in the application.properties file.