# Grails: how to remove AppName from production url

Tags: grails, tomcat7, reverse-proxy, grails-2.2

I am trying to deploy `Grails 2.2.3` project to a production and having issue with URL.
I setup reverse proxy in Apache and have http://example.com -- as example.

I set following property in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://example.com/"
```

and set in the `application.properties` following:

```
app.context=/
```

However all of my resources and links always reference to

```
http://example.com/AppName/...
```

How do I remove application name ("AppName") from resource and links reference?

Example of resources:

```
<r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

Example of environments Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false

        grails.serverURL = "http://example.com/"
        grails.app.context = "/"
    }
}
```

I think Grails application must have some sort of property that could be set!? Otherwise it seems like a pain the neck.

Please help!

P.S: If I access any resource directly (manually remove AppName from URL) I get the right stuff such as css, js and image.

**Update:** 
I set following in application.properties:

```
app.context=/
serverURL=http://example.com/
```

and created absolute URL in grails:

```
<g:createLink controller="Sample" absolute="true"/>
```

and it creates proper URL!!! However resources use relative path and start with AppName/... It seems like a curse, I just can't get rid of that AppName.

**Update:**
If I run `prod run-app` then all URLs come out properly, however the moment I deploy to Tomcat 7, AppName appears in URLs again.

Comment: Should be `grails.app.context='/'`. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539389/change-the-context-for-your-application

Comment: How do you generate your links?

Comment: did you set `grails.serverURL` property in `Config.groovy` for prod environment ?

Comment: Added information to the question

Answer (score 0):

There are other options, but probably the shortest approach is to deploy it like ROOT.war.

Just change the default war filename in the **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
 grails.project.war.file = "target/ROOT.war"
```

Set the right **grails.serverURL** property for you and you're done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't user ROOT.war, is there any other way?

Comment: First check that there is no other app deployed as the ROOT ("/") app in the tomcat, otherwise they will collide. Then try with grails.app.context = '/', but NOT in application.properties (Config.groovy or a properties file using locators).